# Calling COM object methods from native pointers in C#

Tags: c#, com, interop

In C#, is there an easy way to call a COM object method from a native pointer?

```
    [DllImport("d3d11.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private unsafe static extern int D3D11CreateDevice(
        void* arg0, int arg1, void* arg2, int   arg3, void* arg4,
        int   arg5, int arg6, void* arg7, void* arg8, void* arg9);

    public static void CreateDevice()
    {
        unsafe
        {
            IntPtr deviceOut;
            IntPtr immediateContextOut;
            int featureLevelRef;

            D3D11CreateDevice(
                (void*)IntPtr.Zero,
                1,
                (void*)IntPtr.Zero,
                32,
                (void*)IntPtr.Zero,
                0,
                7,
                &deviceOut,
                &featureLevelRef,
                &immediateContextOut);
        }
    }
```

In the code above, I get `deviceOut` whose type is `ID3D11Device*`. The `ID3D11Device` interface has a bunch of methods such as `CreateBuffer()`.

Can I call some of these methods using `deviceOut` pointer? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You'd need to declare the interface.  This has been done, avoid inventing that wheel.  Both SlimDX and SharpDX are favored .NET wrappers for DX11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a pointer to a COM object you can convert it into an instance of the object via `GetObjectForIUnknown`.

```
IntPtr ptr = ...;
object unk = Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(ptr);
ID3D11Device dev = (ID3D11Device)unk;
```

From there you will be able to call the `CreateBuffer` and other methods

Comment: I had to change my comment I made a little while ago. Oddly enough, when you create a DirectX COM object like an IDXGIFactory interface it will already have a ref count greater than zero! I suppose Windows already has one alive or something and it just passed you the pointer to it rather than creating a brand new one from scratch. This seems to be true for other DirectX COM objects as well, like I noticed IDXGIAdapterX interfaces may have a ref count of 4 to 6 already when you obtain them.